# Summation involving binomial coefficients #1

Tags: binomial-coefficients, combinations

I am asked to find the following sum:$$\sum_{i=0}^{100}\binom{k}{i}\binom{M-k}{100-i}\frac{(k-i)}{M-100}$$

The first two terms in the expression i.e, the binomial coefficients is actually $\binom{M}{100}$ as $\binom{k}{i}$ is the coefficient of $x^i$ in $(1+x)^k$ and $\binom{M-k}{100-i}$ is the coefficient of $x^{100-i}$ in $(1+x)^{M-k}$.

Simplifying things I get an answer which is no was close to the actual answer.

Comment: What's the relation between $M$ and $k$ ?. $M < k$ ?. $M \geq k$ ?. $M$ and/or $k$  $\in \mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{N}$ ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that by [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity),
$$\sum_{i=0}^{100}\binom{k}{i}\binom{M-k}{100-i}k=k\sum_{i=0}^{100}\binom{k}{i}\binom{M-k}{100-i}=k\binom{M}{100}$$
and
$$\sum_{i=0}^{100}\binom{k}{i}\binom{M-k}{100-i}i=\sum_{i=1}^{100}\frac{k}{i}\binom{k-1}{i-1}\binom{M-k}{100-i}i=k\sum_{i=1}^{100}\binom{k-1}{i-1}\binom{M-k}{99-(i-1)}\\
=k\sum_{j=0}^{99}\binom{k-1}{j}\binom{M-k}{99-j}=k\binom{M-1}{99}=\frac{k100}{M}\binom{M}{100}.$$
Hence 
$$\sum_{i=0}^{100}\binom{k}{i}\binom{M-k}{100-i}\frac{(k-i)}{M-100}=
\frac{1}{M-100}\left(k\binom{M}{100}-\frac{k100}{M}\binom{M}{100}\right)=
\frac{k}{M}\binom{M}{100}.$$

Comment: Have edited the question again. Please take a look.

Comment: @Anuran Chowdhury Ok. My hint holds also  in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Robert Z ! I will let you know in a while.

Comment: Have you got (k/m)C(m,100)? I did it but tediously

Comment: @Anuran Chowdhury Yes it is correct. See my edited answer.

Comment: I did it by expanding C(n,r) wherever required which make calculations tedious. But Thanks for the help ! This is an elegant way.